# Dúvida em modelagem MongoDB

Tags: modelagem, mongodb

Pelo que estudei, ao modelar uma aplicação utilizando o MongoDB deve-se sempre pensar na aplicação. 
Pensando em um sistema que possui Promoção e Genero, onde uma promoção possui um Genero, vi que será necessário uma tela para cadastrar as promoções e uma tela onde irei apresentar todos os Generos e ao clicar em um todas as Promoções daquele Genero.
No exemplo acima qual a melhor maneira de se trabalhar? Faria com ReferenceDocuments ou com EmbeddedDocuments?
No caso do EmbeddedDocuments como ficaria a buscar para trazer os Generos?

Muito obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo os teus requisitos você poderia ter um documento de promoção, em que o gênero é um atributo. Algo assim:

```
{
  "_id" : "ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea")",
  "tituloPromocao" : "Promoção legal com vários premios",
  "dataInicial" : "2017-05-01",
  "dataFinal" : "2017-05-31",
  "genero" : "genero exemplo"
}
```

Para buscar todos os gêneros na collection de promoções você pode usar o *distinct*, considerando que o nome da collection é "promo":

```
db.promo.distinct("genero");
```

O parâmetro indica qual campo você quer retornar os valores distintos. É interessante você adicionar um índice nesse campo, para otimizar a busca por gênero e o próprio distinct.

Você pode guardar os gêneros possíveis em outra collection, com um documento só, por exemplo:

```
{
   "generos" : ["Pizza","Calzone"]
}
```

Assim você consegue popular uma seleção na interface com as opções possíveis. E pode fazer outra tela para manter os gêneros. Dessa maneira você não precisa fazer o distinct toda vez que vai buscar os gêneros possíveis. Isso tudo considerando que o seu gênero é somente uma String.

Outra opção seria considerar o gênero como um subdocumento, dentro da promoção:

```
{
  "_id" : "ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea")",
  "tituloPromocao" : "Promoção legal com vários premios",
  "dataInicial" : "2017-05-01",
  "dataFinal" : "2017-05-31",
  "genero" : { "id" : "pizza", "descricao" : "Gênero da pizza"}
}
```

E guardar o gênero em outra collection:

```
{
   "id" : "pizza"
  ,"descricao" : "Gênero da pizza"
  ,"nroPromocoes" : 7
}
```

Essa abordagem só faria sentido se você tem mais informações para guardar do gênero, coloquei o número de promoções ali como exemplo. Se essa informação é muito importante para a aplicação, se você vai acessar esse número com muita frequência, então guarde esse valor. Assim você não precisa contar o número de promoções toda vez. Leve em consideração que isso tem um custo: se você alterar a descrição do gênero precisa alterar todas as promoções que usam esse gênero. Se você associar uma promoção a um gênero, precisa alterar o contador de promoções do gênero.

A orientação geral sobre a modelagem com o MongoDB é: **sempre estruture seus dados pensando em como você vai acessar/modificar/inserir/excluir as informações**.

Comment: Entendi. E aí eu poderia ter na tela de cadastro da Promoção no campo Genero ao invés de digitar ter um campo select para evitar o risco de ter os gêneros "Pizza" e "Piza". É mais ou menos por aí?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Se você tem um conjunto de gêneros fixos pode usar uma lista constante no código, ou outra collection em que você guarda  um documento com os gêneros, ex.: `{"generos" : ["Pizza","Calzone"]}`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou demais!

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida. No caso do Gênero ter outras informações como "descrição" por exemplo, eu sei que eu posso ter um "objeto" Gênero dentro da Promoção com todas as suas informações. Se eu manter uma outra colection para guardar os gêneros como você sugeriu eu vou ter uma repetição de informações. Isso dentro do MongoDB não é "errado" pelo que eu entendi, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Não é errado, mas tem um custo. Se você vai usar o mesmo gênero para várias promoções, teria que repetir as informações várias vezes. Se fosse atualizar esse gênero teria que atualizar em todas as promoções que usam ele. Vou atualizar a resposta adicionando essa alternativa.