# Otimização com MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Estou começando com o MongoDB e estou com uma dúvida sobre otimização.

**COLLECTION BOLAO:**

```
[
campeonato : 'Brasil - Série A',
confrontos : [
{
  id : 10,
  casa : "Sport",
  visitante : "Chapecoense",
  horario : "2017-07-20 11:00:00"
}
]
]
```

**COLLECTION APOSTADOR: MODO 1** Assim usaria menos dados, mas pensando um pouco relacional

```
{
  nome : "wedson",
  apostas : [
   {
     idjogo : 10,
     opcao : 1,
     valores : 1
   }
  ]
}
```

**COLLECTION APOSTADOR MODO 2** Assim usaria o conceito de documentos embutidos, mas a carga de dados séria maior

```
{
  nome : "wedson",
  apostas : [
   {
      id : 10,
     casa : "Sport",
     visitante : "Chapecoense",
     horario : "2017-07-20 11:00:00"
     idjogo : 10,
     opcao : 1,
     valores : 1
   }
  ]
}
```

a dúvida é usar o modo 1 onde ou modo 2, não queria começar um projeto sem saber esses pequenos detalhes desde já agradeço. :)

Comment: É um modelo diferente, mas respondi uma questão parecida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206726/d%C3%BAvida-em-modelagem-mongodb). Acho que vale a leitura!