# Nested documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida que acredito ser básica para quem está começando com nosql e é oriundo das estruturas relacionais clássicas.

Bom, tenhamos em vista um exemplo simples para estruturas relacionais:

- Tenho a tabela pessoa com id e nome_pessoa;
- Tenho a tabela endereço com id, id_pessoa, logradouro e número;

Na descrição acima tenho um relacionamento básico um para muitos onde uma pessoa tem muitos endereços. Num CRUD padrão eu consigo atualizar um endereço da pessoa com o id do endereço. Se eu quiser listar todos os endereços de uma pessoa também é simples, simplesmente filtrando a tabela de endereço pelo id_pessoa.

Agora vamos para o nosql. Nas buscas que eu fiz, o ideal é o endereço ser um sub-documento do documento pessoa, que ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
"Pessoa":{
  "_id": "12asdf213",
  "nome": "João da Silva",
  "endereços": [{
    "logradouro": "Vila do Chavez",
    "numero": 71
  }, {
    "logradouro": "Cidade Z"
    "numero": 14
  }]
}
```

A minha dúvida é, como eu poderia atualizar o numero do logradouro da "Vila do Chavez" sem ter um identificador?

Em pesquisas também encontrei que posso referenciar, criando um documento para o endereço e fazendo um relacionamento comum entre os dois documentos. Mas que para o nosql não é muito performático nem indicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como eu poderia atualizar o numero do logradouro da "Vila do Chavez"
>   sem ter um identificador?

Você respondeu a pergunta fazendo ela, "... atualizar o número do logradouro da 'Vila do Chavez' ..." você usou o campo logradouro como identificador.

**Sendo objetivo**: você precisa de um identificador no subdocumento para saber qual deles atualizar. Pode criar um ID, ou buscar pelo nome, como você vai buscar pelo documento pai primeiro, não vejo problema em identificar o sub-documento pelo campo do logradouro mesmo. Lembre-se que se você estiver alterando esse campo você vai precisar guardar o valor antigo.

Copiei esse trecho abaixo de uma outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206726/d%C3%BAvida-em-modelagem-mongodb/) minha, vale ler ela inteira para ajudar no conceito.

> A orientação geral sobre a modelagem com o MongoDB é: sempre estruture
>   seus dados pensando em como você vai acessar/modificar/inserir/excluir
>   as informações.

Comment: Obrigado. Imaginei que essa poderia ser a resposta. Mas me soa estranho, até mesmo por passar anos trabalhando com bancos relacionais. Mas acredito que isso é característica da modelagem.